# Add Images to TableView cells from Firebase in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I am making a social App with Firebase - I want to take each picture the user has uploaded (each user upload only 1 picture) and add it to an array, and then to show it in each cell (each cell is different user with his uniqe uploaded image).

So far I haven't even have any code because i have no idea where to start.. /:

Comment: Have you see Firebase Storage? https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/

Answer (score 0):

Firebase provides no simple way to upload profile pictures for users. I would suggest using a 3rd party site, such as [Cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com/). Then, you will store a link to an image in your user's profile information, using a unique identifier (I would recommend by user ID). Now, you have a whole bunch of user objects with their own profile picture URL's.

Next step, we need to load these URL's to become images in table view cells. 
To do this, there's a great library called [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) that allows you to asynchronously load images from URL's. This means, they will load in without interupting anything else you are trying to do on that controller, and will show a placeholder image until fully loaded. Once you add this library, you have 2 steps:

First step: Import

```
#import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"
```

Next step: Load the image w/ placeholder in cellForRowAtIndexPath (Use a custom cell that has a UIImageView inside it).

```
//user.picUrl is this specific user's profile picture URL
//placeholder.png is a png file in your project's resources
[cell.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:user.picUrl placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```